# Without root, how to make programs use a specific PHP version instead of the default?

Tags: php

I've run into the following situation:

- Managed Server (Webserver, Debian jessie) with SSH access
- Server has several PHP version installed
- `php` is a symlink to `php4` which is a symlink to `php4.4`
- PHP binaries sit in both, `/usr/local/bin` as well as `/usr/bin/`
- No root privileges to change the symlinks

Now, whenever I run a script/program from the command line that calls PHP (either a PHP script, or for example python scripts that will run the PHP interpreter), it will use `php4.4`, which is way too old and leads to errors in every and any script.

I've tried adding this to my `.bash_profile`:
`alias php='/usr/local/bin/php7.1`

Now, when I run `php -v`, it actually uses `php7.1`. However, scripts that I run seem to still use `php4.4` (judging by the same errors they produce, that are tied to old PHP versions).

Is there any other way I can trick scripts/programs into using `php7.1` even though I can't change the symlinks? I know I can possibly edit the scripts and change their shebangs or similar, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Do you use shebang in the scripts? Then using '#!/usr/local/bin/php7.1' could do the trick

Comment: @stoney Good point - one of the scripts is using a shebang, and I successfully employed that trick to get them to work. Sadly, this is not possible for some others (for example a rather complex pieces of Python). Plus, those scripts will be overwritten whenever I update the underlying system (a CMS in this case), so it doesn't seem a good solution to have to change the shebangs over and over.

Comment: So how do these python-scripts call php? /usr/bin/php or just php? What about telling the "manager" to switch to php7.1 as standard?

Comment: I'm not sure about the python script. I'm just hoping to find a workaround that allows me _not_ to mess with the scripts individually. The sever host has been contacted and told me that they are unable or unwilling to change the default php version.

Comment: It's hard to tell what would be best in your setting. The total lack of cooperation from the host dowsn't help either there. Seems you are lost (a server-restart might chip your alias in, but that depends on the server setup).

Comment: The best solution might be to move to another server with a cooperative sysadmin. But try this. `ln -s /usr/local/bin/php7.1 ~/bin/php` and then put `~/bin` at the front of your path. Doesn't help with scripts that have a shebang but the only way to change what an explicit shebang calls is to change the shebang.